# Mongoose query - remove document conditional on subdocument value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to remove a document in the "challenges" collection, but only when the user is in the participant list for that challenge with the admin role.

My current code logs `challenge deleted` , however the challenge isn't actually removed.

Here is the challenge schema:

```
var challengeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type: String, required: true},
    description : {type: String, required: true},
    startDate: {type: Date, required: true},
    endDate: {type: Date, required: true},
    creationDate: {type: Date, required: true},
    goalType : {type: String, required: true},
    goalAmount: {type: Number, required: true},
    participants : {type : [], required: true},
    categories : {type: [String], required: true}
});
```

And below is the current attempt at the query, where `Challenge` is the model variable:

```
    Challenge.findOne({"_id" : req.params.challengeId, "participant" : {
        $elemMatch : {participantID : req.user.id, participantRole : "admin"}
    }}).remove(function(err, challenge){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
        }
        if (!challenge){
            console.log("no challenge found");
            res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
        }
        else {
            console.log("challenge deleted");
            res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is `req.user.id`? Is it a value that is actually stored as an `ObjectId` in the document? If so, you have no schema set for the array entries and mongoose does not know how to "autocast" that value. Hence a 'string' does not match an `ObjectId` since they are of a different type.

Comment: Right, makes sense. So in my model I could create a second schema for the participant and the replace the participant line in the challenge schema with participants : {type : [participantSchema], required: true},

Comment: Well you can either do something like `participants: [participantSchema]` or you can do `participants: [{ participantID: Schema.Types.ObjectId, participantRole: String }]` or whatever fields you actually have. Point is if the "string" from a request parameter needs "casting", then either define the schema to allow "autocasting" or cast the value yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use findOneAndRemove Instead of findOne.
Like This:

```
Challenge.findOneAndRemove({"_id" : req.params.challengeId, "participant" : {
    $elemMatch : {participantID : req.user.id, participantRole : "admin"}
}},function(err, challenge){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
    }
    if (!challenge){
        console.log("no challenge found");
        res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
    }
    else {
        console.log("challenge deleted");
        res.redirect('/user/dashboard');
    }
})
```

Comment: That's not it. `remove()` and `findOneAndRemove()` do the same thing. Besides, it's already been identified what the real problem is.

Comment: This was helpful as my method was passing something unexpected in to the callback in .remove(). However I still needed to fix the nested schema as suggested by @Neil Lunn, and also fix the naming error from participant to participants in the query filters. Thanks all

Comment: It Was A Pleasure. :) @GrepGrep